# XSLT - How to find greatest date and place value in another element

Tags: xml, xslt

**I have the following XML:**

```
<Loans>
  <Loan>
    <LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
      <LoanSecondaryStatus>
        <StatusName>Status1</StatusName>
        <StatusDate>2015-12-21</StatusDate>
      </LoanSecondaryStatus>
      <LoanSecondaryStatus>
        <StatusName>Status2</StatusName>
        <StatusDate>2015-12-23</StatusDate>
      </LoanSecondaryStatus>
    </LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
    <LoanSecondaryStatus>Need status name from greatest status date value here (in this case Status2 would be the value)</LoanSecondaryStatus>
  </Loan>
</Loans>
```

**Current XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="LoanSecondaryStatus[StatusDate='1900-01-01T00:00:00']"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Goal:** 
I need to put the latest date from the "LoanSecondaryStatus" nodes and place the "StatusName" as the "LoanSecondaryStatus" value. How can I achieve this using XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of date formatting, you can simply sort by string value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Loan/LoanSecondaryStatus">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="/Loans/Loan/LoanSecondaryStatusDates/LoanSecondaryStatus">
        <xsl:sort select="StatusDate" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:value-of select="StatusName"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```